# How can I force InitializeComponent code to use the IContainer (this.components) constructor on my user component?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have made a component which needs to access all other components/controls on a form, it inherits the Component and has two constructors

```
public MyComponent(IContainer container)
```

and

```
public MyComponent()
```

The former is never used in the designer generated code.  How can I tell the designer to use it always (and instanciate this.components if needed)?  I need the outcome to be like this:

```
this.myComponent1 = new MyComponent(this.components);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can explicitly call the constructor after InitializeComponent. Still i would like to know what component you are using and passing ?